# Java - Garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

*I found very less understanding in web about java gc. I request you to answer or correct my questions possibly by providing some reliable sources. I hope this post will be helpful to many people like me.*

**Q1) Please correct or improve my understanding about garbage collection:**

gc will automatically be called by jvm during the execution of an application. Calling gc explicitly may only make the gc happen little early than it may happen without explicit call. JVM may call gc at irregular intervals, probably frequently.

gc may collect an object when (i) It's not being referenced by. and (ii) It's not referencing to.
but before destroying an object it will call finalize method of that object class where it can execute some code, normally cleanup operations wrt that object. Finalize method will be called only once per one object. If object is saved by finalize method at the first time, next time it can't escape from death.

If there are memory blocks allocated but not reclaimed due to exceptions/thread abortions they are called as memory leaks which may result in scarcity of memory in the system. OS may tackle with it but not in expected response time of running applications which need memory immediately on demand in which case applications may halt/hang with insufficient memory resource error dumps.

Q2) **Garbage collection will only be for heap?** ( That means, only to collect unreferenced objects? ) If so, what about static variables/constants/objects which are stored in class-method area?

Q3) **How can we make a java object imperishable?** Meaning... No matter what happens in the application, the object should not be reclaimed by gc through out the application life. Is it possible?

Q4) I am guessing there will be some occasions in program where gc may go wrong...meaning reclaim an object which shouldn't reclaim because it may gonna be used but gc didn't see the future use. **Do such mistakes possible about what programmer should suspect or take care of this auto gc provided by java?**

Answer (score 3):

There are many wrong facts in your understanding.

1. Exceptions and thread abortions don't cause memory leaks. Memory leaks only happen when you keep references to objects for too long. A memory leak is thus caused by a bug in *your* code (or in a library that you're using), but not by the JVM.
2. A GC collects objects when the object is not reachable from any chain of references from a root object (variable on a thread stack or static variable). An object which still has references to other objects is not a problem at all. An object which is still referenced by other objects, but not reachable anymore is eligible to GC as well. That's what allows building complex graphs of objects with cyclic references without any problem.
3. Calling gc explicitly may cause GC to execute immediately, later, or not have any effect.
4. If the GC was buggy, it would be useless. It's not buggy. If it reclaims an object, then this object is not used anymore by the application.

To make an object not perishable, just make sure it's always reachable through a chain of references from a root. It could b referenced from a static variable, or by a local variable from a thread that never ends.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 and Q2 I will try explaining how the variables get stored in JAVA, thus u can see how GC works.

If you declare

> Object a ;

you have created a pointer to an object. It gets stored in the STACK but not in the HEAP.
If you later say

> a = new Object();

The object gets placed into the HEAP. The pointer in the stack points to the place in the heap where your object is.
Further more, if you later write

> a = null;

you have set the pointer in the STACK to nowhere. GC will destroy the item in the HEAP. Please note that the pointer is still in the STACK. Now if that all was a local variable ( inside function ) and the function exits at some time, the pointer in the STACK  will be removed too, if it points at something in the heap, it gets removed too.

However if the variable belongs to an object that is let's say instance variable, the pointer will stay until the object itself exists - the object has memory allocated in the HEAP.

I hope you see what's  going on here. It's a bit like chain reaction.

Q3 - You can make an object last until the program exits  by making it STATIC.
About Q4 I am not quite sure.

Comment: `You can make an object last until the program exits by making it STATIC`. Although true 95% of the time, there is, how-ever, another scenario. Static objects only remain un-perishable until the class loader (that was responsible for loading up this static class) avoids GC. Once this class loader gets picked up by the garbage collector, all static classes associated with this loader will also be elected for GC

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of 4) the only time the GC can reclaim object you don't expect is when you play with References such as WeakReference and SoftReference.  These wrapper allow the GC to clean up objects either on a collection, or when memory is low respectively.  While this sounds like a great idea for caching it often doesn't behave quite the way you would expect and they are not as useful as they first appear.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q1)** Please correct or improve my understanding about garbage collection

(Most of your assumptions are correct)

A big problem in programming was memory management . At the begining the developers were responsible for its allocation
and release manually, which led to many bugs and memory leaks. Today , in
all modern platforms , including Java , the memory management is done by GC algorithms.

The Garbage Collector ( GC ) is a major component of the JVM and responsible
by releasing the memory that is no longer being used. When the
application releases all references to an object, it can be collected by the GC at any time, but the time is not determined. It depends entirely on the algorithm the garbage collector . In general , the GC will not make collections for each object. It will wait to release 
blocks of objects, for optimization.

JVM may call gc at irregular intervals, probably frequently. (realy depends on the algorithm)

> **Q2) Garbage collection will only be for heap?**

**NO**. The **PermGen** is out of the **HEAP**. Is where Class objects, Method, and the pool of strigs are allocated. 
**This space is also collected by the GC** (when the FullGC is executed).

[image]

> **Q3) How can we make a java object imperishable?**

If you have an objected that is **never dereferenced**, then it will always exist. (For example, in a web app, you add an object
in the applicationContext and you never take it from there. It will exist for the entire application, until it is shutdown).

> **Q4) Do such mistakes possible about what programmer should suspect or take care of this auto gc provided by java?**

You should be aware of which GC algorithm your JVM is using, and choose one that best suit your needs.

(you can choose UseParallelGC / UseSerialGC / UseParallelOldGC / UseConcMarkSweepGC)

See here :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Your understanding seem to be right except that OS doesn't do anything to reclaim the memory. When jvm starts you provide with the max heap that program can use and once that is completely used you will get an Out of Memory Error if there is a leak in the system. I also don't think that if you save your object in finalize it will cleaned up next time for sure. I think if you make finalize to reference your object back then it might never be cleaned up, i am not sure though.
2. The class and other static information goes to perm gen space. Once the program is restarted this area gets cleared up, but its possible to keep an handle of these information leaking which might result into Out of memory in perm gen space.
3. Make your object global and it will stay forever
4. GC has a small pause time where it rescues the objects which have been reference back. So NO you don't have to worry about GC claiming objects that are not supposed to.

Comment: What is a `global object` in Java ?

Comment: What i mean is that if you define an object in your main method and never assign it to null that object will always stay.